# Bottleneck in population that is already experiencing inbreeding depression

Tags: population-genetics, population-dynamics

What would be the result when a population experiences a bottleneck, while already manifesting inbreeding depression?

I only found [this article](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/303312) and it suggests that the inbreeding depression would decrease by a few points. I couldn't find anything else relevant, only about how a bottleneck increases inbreeding (obviously).

What are the relevant Mathematics?